# Visual Studio: Undetected build error in Target Framework 3.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have been dealing with this problem for a week now.. When I compile my code in VS studio's default target framework - net 4.5.2 it compiles and works fine.. However, when I change the target framework to net 3 it compiles fine but it does not work properly.. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace HourGlass
{
  class MainClass
  {
      [DllImport("User32.dll")]
      public static extern int GetAsyncKeyState(Int32 i);
      public static void Main()
      {
          DoStuff();
      }

      public static void DoStuff()
      {
        string appendText = "";
        bool changeMode = false;
        KeysConverter converter = new KeysConverter();

        while (true)
        {
          Thread.Sleep(5);
          for (Int32 i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
          {
            int key = GetAsyncKeyState(i);
            if (key == 1 || key == -32767)
            {
              if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Shift && converter.ConvertToString(i).ToLower() == "space")
              {
                changeMode = !changeMode;
                if (changeMode)
                {
                  Console.WriteLine("Mode Changed Set True");
                }

                else if (!changeMode)
                {
                  Console.WriteLine("Mode Changed Set False");
                }

                Thread.Sleep(1250);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: The key detection does not work

Comment: Key detection dos not work - when compiled on target framework net 3

Comment: Can you show the error you get?

Comment: You see, this program would printout text onto console everytime I press "shift + space".. However;
It works fine when built on framework version 4.5.2 and here is the screenshot of it working: https://imagebin.ca/v/3u1ut68dy2ZC
But when I change the target framework to 3.0: https://imagebin.ca/v/3u1vnbqifmNL, My program does not work anymore: https://imagebin.ca/v/3u1w7u5WJe9A

Comment: And no, there are no detected errors, it works fine, it just.. well.. does not work..

Comment: Another note, when I change its target framework to version 3 it does not work anymore, and when I revert it back to version 4.5.2 it still does not work. When I create a new project with default target framework (4.5.2) it works again.. I don't know why this is..